# Copy Views from QA to PROD programmatically in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to get views from QA to PROD with scripts.

I am already looking into options like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` or `sql_modules`, but one of the issue for those tables is that the view I have containing comment, and those two options returns code in one line, and the code got issue because the code become commented out.
Ex:

```
Select *  -- test comment
from t1 -- test comment1
join t2 on t2.id = t1.id  -- test comment2
```

to

```
Select *  -- test comment from t1 -- test comment1 join t2 on t2.id = t1.id  -- test comment2
```

I also tried `sp_helptext` to get code in txt format in multiple lines, but the problem of this options is for some of the views, it returns code in half like this, and I am not able to run it

```
Select *  fr
om t1 joi
n t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Right now, I am simply using SSMS options.
Right click on views -> Script Views as -> Create Or Alter to -> New Query Window
Is there a way to run the above steps in code instead of SSMS?

Comment: *"those two options returns code in one line"* Sounds like you are using SSMS to copy the values from a Grid View and don't have "Retain CR/LF on copy or save" enabled.

Comment: If you always used `/* ... */` to write comments you would not have a problem.

Comment: In regards to `sp_helptext`, each row can only have up to 255 characters (as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks)), if you have a row with more than that then the line wraps to the next row: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/la5KZ7Cr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys.sql_modules to get code for a view, and put it into variable, and then execute it in your new database. Something like this untested code:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = definition
from anotherdb.sys.sql_modules
where object_id = object_id('anotherdb..someview');
exec(@sql);
```

To get multiple view, use a cursor or a loop to fetch many view names